# What is the opposite of Halo effect?

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests

I'm looking for a word or idiom that is the opposite of **Halo effect**?

> Halo effect (sometimes called the halo error) is the tendency for positive impressions of a person, company, brand or product in one area to positively influence one's opinion or feelings in other areas.Halo effect is “the name given to the phenomenon whereby evaluators tend to be influenced by their previous judgments of performance or personality. [Wikipedia]

So what word or expression would describe the tendency to overlook a person's pluses just because of their shortcomings in a certain area?

Comment: Not quite an "effect" in the sense that you're looking for, but smear, stain and black spot all come to mind.

Comment: @Karl Thanks, but this is too vague.

Comment: I'm trying to remember the cartoon character who was always drawn with a rain cloud over his head.

Comment: @HotLicks, I can't remember about the character with the rain cloud, but Pigpen was almost always drawn with a cloud of dirt?

Comment: I'd suggest "negative halo effect". If "halo effect" is well understood by your audience that should be, too.

Comment: @HotLicks https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Btfsplk

Comment: Well, I was going to say "horny effect," but then I heard it in my head and realized that it would probably get interpreted as specifically sexual, so probably not a good idea, even if it is technically an opposite adjective for "halo," angels wearing halos and devils having horns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Guilt by association** is usually applied to human agents as the guilty party, but there are broadenings to behaviours, choices, even agents neither sentient nor the result of human creation.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_fallacy) gives a broadened definition:

> An association fallacy is an informal inductive fallacy of the
> hasty-generalization or red-herring type and which asserts, by
> irrelevant association and often by appeal to emotion, that qualities
> of one thing are inherently qualities of another. [One] type of
> association fallacy is sometimes referred to as *guilt by
> association*....

Examples showing extended usage:

> - *Christa is thinking about becoming a vegetarian. Then she learns that many mass murderers were also vegetarians. So, she keeps eating*
>   *meat*.

[[SoftSchools.com](https://www.softschools.com/examples/fallacies/guilt_by_association_examples/494/)]

('Vegetarianism, associated with mass murderers, is best avoided.')

> - **Cancer Guilt by Association**
>
> By Science News StaffNov. 6, 1996 , 8:00 PM
>
> A new set of criteria to judge whether a chemical is likely to cause
> cancer in humans will get a trial run later this month when a select
> group of federal scientists will pick a handful of compounds to
> undergo a battery of tests. But the rules, which rely on a chemical's
> structure alone to judge its potential for causing cancer, may
> eventually be tested themselves –in court.
>
> Over the last few years new insights into how chemicals cause cancer
> have prompted federal agencies to revise their approaches to assessing
> cancer risk. With such data in mind, the National Toxicology Program
> (NTP), a federal effort to study the most suspicious chemicals,
> recently revised its Biennial Report on Carcinogens (BRC) –a
> compendium that lists substances known or thought to cause human
> cancer. The new guidelines say that a substance or mixture, even if
> there is insufficient evidence to classify it as a carcinogen, can be
> proposed for listing if it "belongs to a well-defined, structurally
> related class of substances" whose members are listed in a previous
> BRC. For instance, new types of polycyclic aromatic hydrocarbons, a
> common industrial pollutant, would be guilty by association. "We can
> do more with the science now, and we need to," says an NTP
> spokesperson.

[[Science](https://www.sciencemag.org/news/1996/11/cancer-guilt-association)]

(Compounds with structures resembling those of known carcinogens can automatically be added to the list of carcinogens [and this article says they need testing on an individual basis instead].)